# Venus fly trap tag malfunctioning

Tags: discussion, support, bug

The [venus-fly-trap](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venus-fly-trap) appears to exist, and [dionaea](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dionaea) the species name tag also exists and is a synonym of it. The issue is that neither of them can be used to tag a question. Searching the tags for venus-fly-trap yields no results, but dionaea does. Is this a bug?

Comment: You need 150 rep to create a tag; now that you're over that threshold, please try again. There is a script that removes single-use tags after six months, which may be what happened to the original tags. The synonym mappings are in a separate database table and don't get removed; I would imagine so that if a tag gets recreated after removal, the synonyms are reinstated.